# How can the variable computed in the previous epoch be used for computing the loss function in the next epoch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss

The pytorch code is given below. How can the variable computed in the previous epoch be used for
computing the loss function in the next epoch?

```
for epoch in range((args.start_epoch+1), args.epochs):
  
    for input, target in train_loader:
        target = target.cuda()
        input = input.cuda()
        input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)
        target_var = torch.autograd.Variable(target)
        outputs, feature = model(input_var)

        if epoch > 0:
            l = criterion.forward(feature,target_var, Fea)

    Fea = function(model,train_loader)
```

Comment: Please improve the code formatting.

Comment: "How can the variable computed in the previous epoch be used for computing the loss function in the next epoch?"

You can store it to a variable.

Comment: Consider making `Fea` global.

Comment: First of all how `Fea` came here in the line `l = criterion.forward(feature,target_var, Fea)`? You should have initialized it before. Hence, there is no point of facing such problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for  afagarap and  hafiz031.

Comment: l= criterion(feature,target_var, Fea).forward() l.backward(retain_graph=True) may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for epoch in range((args.start_epoch+1), args.epochs):
```

Center= computer_Center(model,dataloader, classnum)
for input, target in train_loader:
target = target.cuda()
input = input.cuda()
input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)